# Pass and store static function pointer in constructor

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a class Foo.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int(_bar)(const int);

    Foo(int(bar)(const int))
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }
};
```

I am trying to pass in a pointer to a static function on creation, and retain that in the class so I can call it later.

I am getting an error of...

```
error C2659: '=' : function as left operand
```

...but I don't understand why.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function:

```
int(_bar)(const int);
```

Function pointer:

```
int(*_bar)(const int);
```

You just forgot the `*`

Comment: Thanks. But why is this not needed on the param?

Comment: It is needed if you want to take a function pointer as a parameter, the error just happens to occur on the member because you are trying to assign to it, which you can do with a function pointer but not with a function (if that even makes sense).

Comment: So is Foo(int(bar)(const int)) invalid as a constructor definition if I were to pass the method like so: Foo(&someStaticFunc);

Comment: ...because it does compile?

Comment: Well interestingly enough, in a parameter declaration contexte it seems you can assign a parameter of type `function` when you call the function taking that parameter, it does probably act as a function pointer, but in other contexts (within a class, function, or the global scope) that does not work.